# Firebase Cloud Messaging: sending to multiple specific users

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In the [legacy HTTP protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref), the `registration_ids` field exists to specify multiple recipients.

However in the [new HTTP protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages), such field is not present anymore.

Does it mean it is not possible to send the same message to multiple users anymore?

Comment: What type of server do you have?

Comment: I still have to set it up. I am thinking to use the new HTTP protocol, as suggested in the documentation.

Comment: If you use Node.js you can use the Admin SDK - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages

Comment: I am using Go on the server.